# manage.py migrate not working after a table has been dropped and re-created

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm developing an app changing the models a lot. I created a table, changed the fields, and since it's only play data there was no point in keeping it.

So I did:

```
python manage.py dbshell
sqlite> .table
auth_group                  django_admin_log          
auth_group_permissions      django_content_type       
auth_permission             django_migrations         
auth_user                   django_session            
auth_user_groups            products_produit          
auth_user_user_permissions
sqlite> DROP TABLE products_produit 
   ...> ;
sqlite> .table
auth_group                  auth_user_user_permissions
auth_group_permissions      django_admin_log          
auth_permission             django_content_type       
auth_user                   django_migrations         
auth_user_groups            django_session
```

Table `products.produit` is indeed gone. I also delete migration files (e.g. 000X_.py). There are indeed no more migration files under /migration/, only `__init__.py`.

I updated my model and re-ran make migrations:

```
Migrations for 'products':
  products/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Produit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It created the migration, I see all expected fields. However, when I ran migrate nothing happened:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, products, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The table still isn't there:

```
sqlite> .table
auth_group                  auth_user_user_permissions
auth_group_permissions      django_admin_log          
auth_permission             django_content_type       
auth_user                   django_migrations         
auth_user_groups            django_session            
sqlite>
```

There is *some* trace left of the former table, even though it was dropped. What do I need to do if I want to drop the table to completely start anew?

The issue isn't with my new model because makemigrations succeeded and if I remove the db.sqlite3 file (and create a superuser anew etc.) the `product.produit` table is migrated as expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django adds a table to your database to manage what has been migrated. You can see the table `django_migrations`. You are in the situation that you deleted the table yourself, while the entry for it's migration was left in `django_migrations`. To fix this the simplest way would be to fake a migration to zero:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake products zero
```

Comment: Sir, when i run this command that time some doubt and error occurred please check my question once a time --> [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66446770/14131913)

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. I notice that my ALL my files were not saved. After turning on VSCODE Auto Save, my migrations worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that the author does not specify if they are using VSCode, nor is this answer directly tied to the problem described. Please consider making sure that your answers match the problem posed by the original poster.