# python manage.py migrate --fake <appname> vs python manage.py migrate --fake <appname> zero

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-migrations

When I run `python manage.py migrate --fake photos  zero` :

> Operations to perform:
> Unapply all migrations: photos
> Running migrations:   Rendering model states... DONE
> Unapplying
> photos.0001_initial... FAKED

After running above command, I ran `python manage.py migrate` at that time this error occurred.

> Traceback:Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
> line 411, in execute
> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
>
> > django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "photos_userphoto" already
> > exists

When I run `python manage.py migrate --fake photos`:

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: photos Running
> migrations:   Applying photos.0001_initial... FAKED   Applying
> photos.0002_auto_20210303_0120... FAKED

After running above command, I ran `python manage.py migrate` and this work perfectly.

```
Running migrations:
  Applying photos.0003_auto_20210303_0123... OK
```

**So my question is that what difference between `python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>` vs `python manage.py migrate --fake <appname> zero` and Why first command throws me an error?**

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a misunderstanding about the `--fake` flag. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) the `--fake` flag:

> Marks the migrations up to the target one (following the rules above)
> as applied, but without actually running the SQL to change your
> database schema.

It also further states that it is meant for advanced users if they are making changes manually. Basically Django makes a table `django_migrations` to manage your migrations. It adds an entry to it to mark if a migration has been applied. What `--fake` does is simply add / remove the entries to / from this table according to the migration you specify. Also the `zero` means to undo all migrations.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake photos zero
```

The above command means you basically say to Django:

> I have or will manually remove(d) all the tables, etc. from the database
> for the app photos

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>
```

In the above command you don't specify the migration (in previous you specified zero), this means to assume that you mean till the most recent migration. Basically with `--fake` this command means:

> I have or will manually make all the tables, etc. in the database for
> the migrations till the most recent one.

From my understanding you only made some changes and wanted to update your database, for this you could have simply written:

```
python manage.py migrate
```